# Saving in 2 different models, One could have many fields saved at the same moment

Tags: python, django, list, django-models, django-crispy-forms

I'm having this problem and I need an idea how to solve it cause I need it for a lot of things.
I will try to be as clear as I can with what I need.

First what I want to do is a medical prescription for drugs, so I need to save the data of a patient and as many drugs and the doctor ask for the patient.
So I have 2 models, the patient data model and the drugs model.

**models.py**

```
class RecipePatientData(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(patientData)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(DoctorData)
    observations = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class PrescriptionDrugs(models.Model):
    recipe_data = models.ForeignKey(RecipePatientData)
    prescripted_drug = models.ForeignKey(Drugs)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    day_of_treatment = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Well my problem is that I don't know who to save the drugs, cause I need to add as many drugs as the doctor want In the same template, I have a button to add new fields for the next drug, I do this by cloning the main form.

[image]

I want to know If theres a way that django can convert the field in lists or something that can help me to save the drugs even if the fields have the same name. I try to do a get them by a cleaned_data in the view, but It only get me the main field, not the clone ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, what you need is [FormSets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/) which let you work with multiples forms on the same page.

Here an example:

```
# forms.py
form django import forms
from your.models import PrescriptionDrugs

class PrescriptionDrugsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
         model = PrescriptionDrugs
         fields = ("__all__")
```

on views.py

```
# views.py
class YourView(FormView):
    template_name = 'template.html'
    form_class = formset_factory(PrescriptionDrugsForm, extra=3) #number of forms
    success_url = '/your-url/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form f in form:
            f.save()
        return super(YourView, self).form_valid(form)
```

on template.html

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.management_for }}
    {% for f in form %}
        {{ f.as_p }}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Comment: If you use a Model Form with formsSet, on inside method `form_valid(self, form): for f in form: f.save()`

Comment: Is there a way to not define the number of extra forms and do it dinamic?

Comment: try with [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#validating-the-number-of-forms-in-a-formset)